# Trying to AJAX an ASP page, but it never hits a success

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

I was working on some code, and cant seem to see why this is always failing.  I had tried to debug it, but the asp page is is referencing will not hit a breakpoint.  (Hint maybe that it isnt fetching the page??).  for the data: part i had it right before the post trying to see if it would do JSON.stringify({variables}) to see if that worked as well, but it did not

Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'AutoComplete.asmx/getWebFormDesignFieldContents',
        data: {
            'fe_name': "*",
            'count': 200,  //this might need to be adjusted slightly.  I may want to make it more OR less.
            'also_search_fe_desc': true,
            'opts': opts
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            //success
            $("div.modal").replaceWith($(result));
            $("div.modal").fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //error
            //alert("Error: "+result.statusText);
            $("div.overlay").fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

On the serverside portion of ASP I have:

```
public String getWebFormDesignFieldContents(String fe_name, int count, bool also_search_fe_desc, String opts)
{
   String retValue = "";
   ...
   return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate your method with `[WebMethod]` attribute

```
[WebMethod]
public String getWebFormDesignFieldContents(
     String fe_name, 
     int count, 
     bool also_search_fe_desc, 
     String opts)
```

Something else you need to change is your json format. You have to pass a string.

```
data:'{"fe_name": "*", "count": 200, "also_search_fe_desc": true, "opts":' + opts + '}'
```

You could use `JSON.stringify` but take into account that old browsers don't have support for it so you may need to handle that situation.

You'll also need to work on your return logic. For now I just see you return an empty string. If you show more code we could help you with that too.

Comment: I did that and it still errors?  Is there a way to make it debug so i can go through the server side piece by piece?  So far, i did your 2 reccomendations.  There is still an error, so i am trying to break inside to see what information i can get get to further fix this issue to make sure the request is not still failing, but something else

Comment: I wrapped the ASP with a try{}catch and then just returned an empty string.

Comment: So, should i do JSON.Stringify({ELEMENETS})

Comment: @Fallenreaper: you could do that. Just take into account that JSON.Stringify is not available for old browsers. That's was the reason why I did it manually.

Comment: KK, i stringified it.  still seems to be failing.  For the error: function(err){Can i say something ehre like alert(err.stackTrace);  or some thing to see what the specific error is, or is it just like a 404 error returned from the target url/

Comment: @Fallenreaper: sorry, I just see that you calling a web service (I thought it was a page web method). The web method don't need to be static. Please test removing that. You can see server answer with firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: Still errors.  Going to run with Chrome quick to see what the ajax response is.  Edit:   Error500, Internal Server Error. Further Information looking at asp page:  No Webservice found at: /AutoComplete.asmx.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint on the server logic to see if reach the code?

Comment: It doesnt hit the breakpoints.  Maybe the URL is wrong in the request.  I thought i had to reference the page/method...  maybe i need to double check the path and do a path/file/method for the URL

Comment: @Fallenreaper: something else that might give you valid information is inspecting `result` on error handler.

Comment: As it says it is an internal server error, i feel the errors are no longer a part of the question at hand.  I believe the base question has been resolved but opening the way for more questions.  I will mark as answered and open a new question.

Comment: Also, for the record, got the server to ping and go into debug.  Was an additional URL error.... It was not associated with the correct path.  Great Job Claudio for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the retValue as json

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonresult = serializer.Serialize(retValue );
```

Comment: why would i need to serialize it?  I was going to take the retValue and pass it into $(result) tags which would parse and set the html elements?